# Should I build a different model for each subset

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, many-categories

I have a dataset which has categorical variable *class* and it has around 10 classes in it. I am trying to solve a *regression* problem

I am not understanding whether I should build a model on entire dataset and consider variable *class* as one of the input variable or for each class should I build a different model altogether.

What are *general* rules which can help me deciding between two approaches.

This is a sample of how my data looks like

```
+------------+----+-----+-----------------+
|   Class    | X1 | X2  |     Speed       |
+------------+----+-----+-----------------+
| Class1     | 12 | 123 |              10 |
| Class2     | 14 | 120 |              32 |
| Class3     | 15 |  34 |              12 |
|   .        |  . |   . |               . |
|   .        |  . |   . |               . |
|   .        |    |     |                 |
|  Class 300 | 23 |  13 |              45 |
+------------+----+-----+-----------------+
```

`Class` is the input categorical variable and I have around 300 classes. The output variable is `Speed`. I am trying to predict the speed with variables `Class`, `X1`, `X2`.

Should I build a model for each `Class` separately. So when I know input type is `Class1` I will select model built for `Class1`. When input type is `Class2` I will use model built for `Class2` and so on.

Other way I was thinking is to include `Class` itself as a variable and just build one model.

I don't know which would be the *correct* way for it

Comment: Can you clarify to see if anyone can help, what do you mean input variable? Is class a dependent/outcome variable or an independent/predictor variable? Are you using a kind of regression or some other analysis? Because you've tagged both regression and machine learning. If you split the levels within class into a single level how will you fit a model, there isn't any anything that varies, unless you mean split them into subsets of level 1 and 2, and level 3 and 4. Lastly, what will you use the model for, estimation or prediction?

Comment: Updated with more relevant information

Comment: This can all be done in one model, no need to train 300 separate models.

Comment: But are there any specific use cases where I should use 300 models instead of 1 model ? Just wanted to ask since I have no idea bout how to deal with this